# python re.findall() only gives me one result

Tags: python, regex

This the sample code:

```
import re

source = """
BEGIN:VEVENT
DTSTART:20160404T113000Z
DTEND:20160404T141500Z
LOCATION:A3006
SUMMARY:[I-EM-3N:Energy Management Gr 3N] Basics of Mathematical Software
END:VEVENT

BEGIN:VEVENT
DTSTART:20160404T113000Z
DTEND:20160404T141500Z
LOCATION:A3007
SUMMARY:[I-EM-3N:Energy Management Gr 3N] Chemistry and Environment
END:VEVENT
"""

pattern = r'BEGIN.*?DTSTART:(\d{4})(\d{2})(\d{2})T(\d{2})(\d{2})\d{2}Z.*?DTEND:(\d{4})(\d{2})(\d{2})T(\d{2})(\d{2})\d{2}Z.*LOCATION:(.*?)\n.*?SUMMARY:\[(.*?):.*?\]\s(.*?)\s?\n.*?END:VEVENT'


s = re.findall(pattern, source, re.DOTALL)
print s
```

The result is [('2016', '04', '04', '11', '30', '2016', '04', '04', '14', '15', 'A3007', 'I-EM-3N', 'Chemistry and Environment')], but where is another one?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You forgot to make one of your wild card matches *non-greedy* (works for me):

```
BEGIN.*?DTSTART:(\d{4})(\d{2})(\d{2})T(\d{2})(\d{2})\d{2}Z.*?DTEND:(\d{4})(\d{2})(\d{2})T(\d{2})(\d{2})\d{2}Z.*?LOCATION:(.*?)\n.*?SUMMARY:\[(.*?):.*?\]\s(.*?)\s?\n.*?END:VEVENT
                                                                                                           HERE^
```

And, since the expression is complex and not quite readable, consider using the ["verbose" mode](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.X):

```
pattern = r"""
BEGIN:VEVENT\n
DTSTART:(\d{4})(\d{2})(\d{2})T(\d{2})(\d{2})\d{2}Z\n
DTEND:(\d{4})(\d{2})(\d{2})T(\d{2})(\d{2})\d{2}Z\n
LOCATION:(.*?)\n
SUMMARY:\[(.*?):.*?\]\s(.*?)\s?\n
END:VEVENT
"""

s = re.findall(pattern, source, re.DOTALL | re.VERBOSE)
print(s)
```

Comment: This is an example where the [`re.X` flag](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.X) is useful.